# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when splitting the line of a text file

Tags: java, split, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to spit this text file:

```
asdf;asdf;asdf;N/A;N/A;N/A;N/A;N/A;N/A;N/A;N/A
```

Just so you know. there is no empty line at the bottom of it. That's all there is.

The piece of code that does this job is this.

```
try{
                s = fIN.readLine();
                while(s != null){
                    Parts = s.split(";");
                    NameFile = Parts[0];
                    IngredientFile[1] = Parts[1];
                    QuantityFile[1] = Parts[2];
                    IngredientFile[2] = Parts[3];
                    QuantityFile[2] = Parts[4];
                    IngredientFile[3] = Parts[5];
                    QuantityFile[3] = Parts[6];
                    IngredientFile[4] = Parts[7];
                    QuantityFile[4] = Parts[8];
                    IngredientFile[5] = Parts[9];
                    QuantityFile[5] = Parts[10];
                    list1.add(NameFile + "\n");
                    for(i=1; i<6; i++){
                        list1.add(" " + IngredientFile[i] + "" + QuantityFile[i] + "\n");
                    }
                    s = fIN.readLine();
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                list1.add(" ERROR READING FILE. \n");
            }
```

It's throwing the error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 on line 45 which is this

```
IngredientFile[1] = Parts[1];
```

Apparently it's the Parts array which is giving me this but that can't be right because I declared it with the size of 1000 just for safety.

```
public String[] Parts = new String[1000];
```

Anyone have any ideas what's going on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Comment: where and how did you declare array  IngredientFile ?

Comment: public String[] IngredientFile = new String[6];

Comment: Thanks you Arnaud, I have seen that article already. But I'm afraid it didn't help.

Comment: Parts = s.split(";"); overwrites your previous initialization. No matter if it was before 1000 cells long, it now is whatever the output of split is. Evidently you have some lines without ';' in your input

Comment: ooops then it seems well try to debug it..check the size of Parts while debugging..

Answer (score 1):

You should check the length of Parts before making assignments to make sure it split correctly or throw an exception if not. In your case, the line probably didn't have any ";" separator.

also, you could eliminate the case where you have an empty line or some weird characters.

```
    if (!s.isEmpty() && !s.trim().equals("") && !s.trim().equals("\n")){
//split
}
```